# Linear Algebra Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need some help on this problem.

Assume that $V$ is a complex vector space. Let $T,S: V \rightarrow V$ be two linear operators such that $TS - ST = S$. Show that:

(a) Let $W$ be the subspace spanned by the eigenvectors of $T$. Show that $W$ is invariant under both $T$ and $S$.

(b) Show that $S_{|W}$ is a nilpotent operator.

(c) Show that there exists a nonzero common eigenvector of $T$ and $S$.

Comment: Do you know what invariant means? Write down the definition and apply it for $T$, then for $S$, using the hypothesis.

Comment: Well, I know that since W is the span of eigenvectors of T, then W must be invariant under T. However, I don't see how I can use that to determine anything about what S does to W.

Comment: Take a typical element of $W$, for starters the simplest case. As i said, you have to use the equation!

Comment: I think you want to assume that V is finite dimensional. At least, that's what it says on the sheet and it seems to help with the proof. I agree with Prof Shifrin's advice: say you have $Tv = \lambda v$. What can you say about $Sv$?

Comment: @DylanMoreland, I take it you know this mysterious user :) Sorry about my rant. I just get irritated by all the folks who deprive students of the joy of wrestling with problems. I assume we use finite-dimensionality in the next part :)

Comment: I take it that by "$S|w$" you mean "$S|_W$", the restriction of $S$ to $W$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose I should answer this.

(a) You should prove that it's enough to show that $Sv \in W$ for any eigenvector $v$ of $T$. Now just start going: write $Tv = \lambda v$, and try to say something interesting about $Sv$ using the formula.

(b) This relies on something you'll discover about eigenvalues in the course of proving (a). It's going to seem sort of surprising. Again, a simplification: it's enough to prove that there is some $n$ such that for each eigenvector $v$ for $T$, $S^nv = 0$. I think you need to use the finite dimensionality of $V$.

(c) Such a vector is lurking in your work for the first two parts.

It's hard to resist mentioning the Lie algebra of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$: take, as an important example, $V = \mathbb C^2$, $T = \frac12 \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ and $S = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.